# How to add a folder Jetty will run a site from?

Tags: jetty, virtualbox

I have Jetty running on an Oracle VBox VM (Win7) Guest. I need Jetty to run a site from a shared folder, so I can edit it on the host. How can I do that?

Edit: The site is HTML/JS, not a war file. I see from the [docs](http://www.baeldung.com/deploy-to-jetty) I can copy a war to `$JETTY_HOME`. What I'm wondering is if I can add a path to `$JETTY_HOME` for Jetty to look in?

The path is `\\VBOXSVR\MyCoolSite`

Comment: You want to serve static content where the base resource path is a UNC path?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Yes, I suppose I do. That's how OVB mounts shared folders to the guest. Furthermore, I've already tested running a static site from `$JETTY_HOME`, and it works, now I'm wondering if I can have the site housed on a network path?